# Integral $\int \frac {f^{(n)}(x)}{f (x)} dx$

Tags: integration

Is there some general formula for  $\displaystyle\int \frac {f^{(n)}(x)}{f (x)} dx$

For $n=1$, we get $\ln (|f (x)|) $

Comment: I do not think so. For example, $\frac{f''}{f'} = \left( \frac{f'}{f'}\right)' + \left( \frac{f'}{f'}\right)^2$ and there is no general formula for $\int \left( \frac{f'}{f'}\right)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $f$ is sufficiently smooth. It already gets hairy with $n=2$. We have
$$\int \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}dx = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \int \left (\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \right )^2dx$$
or for $n=3$
$$\int \frac{f'''(x)}{f(x)}dx = \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} + \int\frac{f''(x)f'(x)}{f(x)^2}dx$$
You could say that
$$ \int \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{f(x)}dx = \frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)}{f(x)} + \int\frac{f^{(n-1)}(x)f'(x)}{f(x)^2}dx$$
but I don't know how much help this is.